# Как правильно проверить значение строки на null?

Tags: java, android, null

Как дополнительно можно проверить или применить к условию, чтоб проверялось значение `null`? Записывать в скобки `isEmpty()` не получается.

```
if (mobile.getOutputMetadata().getVideoUrl().isEmpty())
```

Использую для вводимой строки, ведь строка может быть `null`.

Comment: `== null` ? Я чего-то не понял?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile.getOutputMetadata().getVideoUrl())) {
    ........
}
```

Я правильно понял?

`TextUtils.isEmpty()` проверяет на `null` и на длинну

Comment: Да, вариант подошёл, благодарю.